# Returning count number from ID columns for repeated Id's

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, qsqlquery

The below query returns the correct results, however, it returns all the results.  What I want to do now is to have a column that counts the number of times the id was found in the ID column. Does that make sense?

Here is my query right now.

```
SELECT distinct es.id,es.name,first_name,last_name
--         case when count(ea.id=es.name)>=7 then 'Yes' else 'No' 
END as 
Attended_all
--         count(es.id) as Times_checked_in
FROM    event_session_checkin esc,
        event_attendee ea,
        event_session es
 WHERE  esc.event_attendee_id = ea.id AND es.Id = 
esc.event_session_id
 -- and a.event_session_id = 'session_id' -- ska monday morning;
 AND es.event_id = 'event_id' and 
es.name like 'SKA%'
order by es.id, first_name, last_name;
```

The query is returning these results right now.

The is an example of restults.

```
 ID             name              fname   lname
------|------------------------|-------|------
123        SKA - Monday Morn    Abby    Andrews
123        SKA - Monday Morn    Abraham Chiok
1234       SKA - Monday Morn    Addison Curles
1234       SKA - Monday Morn    Addison White
12345      SKA - Monday Morn    Addisyn Schaefer
12345      SKA - Monday Morn    Addlee  Nelson
```

what i want is to add another column at the end that counts how many times the id number appear in the ID column?  does that make sense?

Comment: Can you provide sample data before you run your SQL?

Comment: You need to read up on `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly well I know what group by does and count does. However I’m thinking I need a subquery l.  Or how would you implement the group by and count in this scenario?

Comment: Which MySQL version you are using currently?

Comment: And also read up on JOIN's

Comment: @RiggsFolly not sure how a JOIN will help me on this one.  it still the same result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai 5.1

Comment: His point is that you are using old school joins. The preferred and superior method is to use ANSI joins.

Comment: @alexherm no, i get it that.  on my actual query i have Joins, just didn't know how is that helpful for what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use windows functions to do this. For example:

```
select 
  *,
  count(*) over (partition by id) as id_count
from ( -- your query enclosed as a table expression here
  SELECT distinct es.id,es.name,first_name,last_name
  --         case when count(ea.id=es.name)>=7 then 'Yes' else 'No' 
  END as 
  Attended_all
  --         count(es.id) as Times_checked_in
  FROM    event_session_checkin esc,
          event_attendee ea,
          event_session es
   WHERE  esc.event_attendee_id = ea.id AND es.Id = 
  esc.event_session_id
   -- and a.event_session_id = 'session_id' -- ska monday morning;
   AND es.event_id = 'event_id' and 
  es.name like 'SKA%'
) x
order by es.id, first_name, last_name
```

Comment: oh i see, this is for mysql 8.1

Comment: The `OVER` clause is part of the SQL standard and implemented in MySQL since version 8.x. That clause modifies the `COUNT(*)` function so it produces the aggregation value on each row, rather than the group, as an unqualified `COUNT(*)` would do.

Comment: ah, got it.  Im running mysql 5.1 though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `GROUP BY` won't work for what (I think) you are trying to do. That's because the `fname` and `lname` are different, so the result rows will not be the same.

If you try to do it all on one query, it will become exponentially slower as you add records - since it would have to run the counts for each row.

I would recommend using a stored procedure and creating a temporary table with the `ID` and `Count` for each. Then `JOIN temp ON es.id = temp.id` in order to include the count on each line.

Comment: Thank you, im not really trying to create a new table, just trying to query.  I may just query as is and then sort it in excel

Comment: Understand that I'm suggesting a temporary table that only exists when the procedure is run. After exiting from the stored procedure, the temporary table ceases to exist.